# How can i configure model builder to delete all recipes when user is deleted but when recipe is deleted keep the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-model-builder

This is my model builder right now, but when i delete user it sets recipes userid to null.

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(e => e.Recipes).WithOne(e => e.ApplicationUser)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasOne(e => e.ApplicationUser).WithMany(e=>e.Recipes)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overstated the mapping, you only need to map one entity to the other.

Try to use this one first;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(e => e.Recipes).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasOne(e => e.ApplicationUser);
```

If the above doesn't work, try this one alone;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(e => e.Recipes).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```